# How to find missing numbers from list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
lst = [1, 4, 5, 9, 6]
```

How to write a code to get some missing values which must return `[2, 3, 7, 8]`?

Here is my code

```
new_list = []
for i in range(1, len(lst1)):
  if i not in lst1:
    new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert them to sets and use "-" to calculate the difference. Note that the order is important.

You need to define what you want to compare your list to if you want to find the missing elements. You can automatically do this if it is simple like "the numbers from 1 to 10" using the code:

```
list(range(1, 10))
```

The comparison code is:

```
lst1 = [1, 4, 5, 9, 6]
lst2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
out = list(set(lst2) - set(lst1))
print(out)
```

which returns

```
[8, 2, 3, 7]
```

It isn't clear exactly what you want from your question, if you give a more detail it will be easier to help.

Comment: I'm assuming OP wants something like: `set(range(min(lst), max(lst)+1)) - set(lst)`.